# More elegant way to disable my LOG messages when unit testing?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, testing

Right now, in visual studio 2017, I'm trying to unit test my code using google's testing framework gtest. I'm coding in C++. The problem I'm having is I want to be able to disable my LOG and assert macros for my debug build when unit testing by I'm not sure how to do this properly. This is currently how I have my macros setup:

```
#if (DEBUG)

#define RUNTIME_ASSERT \
    BOOST_ASSERT_MSG 

#define COMPILETIME_ASSERT(expr, msg) \
    static_assert(expr, msg) 

#define LOG(...) \
    do { fprintf_s(stderr, __VA_ARGS__); } while (0)

#else
#define NDEBUG
#define RUNTIME_ASSERT 
#define COMPILETIME_ASSERT(expr, msg)
#define LOG(...) ((void)0)
#endif
```

My solution consists of two projects, my actual application (a video game project) and a unit test project which takes my game project as a lib to run the tests.

I've tried creating another build configuration like "Debug unit test" though I couldn't quite get things to work and it seems like a sloppy way of doing things as then I would have to keep maintaining changes to both debug and debug unit testing build configurations. Any other suggestions?

Comment: It looks fine to me. You can also try things like CMake and define your configs there.

Comment: Why would you need to disable _static_ asserts in a unit test? If you somehow need to build tests that otherwise shouldn't compile, are they still testing your actual code?

Comment: @Useless Good point, I will change that.

Comment: Secondly, `BOOST_ASSERT_MSG` is already disabled when `NDEBUG` is defined, so you don't need to do something special for that. Just define `DEBUG`/`NDEBUG` correctly.

Comment: @Useless Ha, I figured. Was just being cautious. I'll change that as well!

Comment: @kleszcz One day I'll move to CMake......one day.

Answer (score 0):

The conditional `LOG` macro is OK - this is pretty standard (apart from the fact that you're using a non-standard Microsoft extension to `fprintf`, but whatever).

There is one potential problem, which is that your unit test *will never exercise your log statements*. So, you can potentially have a runtime bug in your `LOG` arguments, which the preprocessor will hide from testing.

The more reliable solution is to have the logging stream defined somewhere rather than hardcoding `stderr`, and then overriding that to a null stream in your unit test setup (or redirect `stderr` - I'm not sure what the Windows equivalent of `/dev/null` is). This way, the arguments to `LOG` are still evaluated, and the formatting is still done, but you still don't see the logging.

---

You don't need to do anything for `static_assert` (because if they ever fail in your test code when they would pass in non-test code ... you're probably not testing the right thing anyway).

You don't need to do anything special for `BOOST_ASSERT_MSG` either, as that's already disabled by `NDEBUG`.